# Como mudar a cor de um único link?

Tags: html, css

Como mudar a cor de um **único** link?

Ja tentei ir em "*Modify - Page properties - Links*", porém as configurações que são colocadas lá vão para TODOS os links, e não é o que quero em meu site.

Comment: Pode ser pela aba *Code*?

Comment: Que tal direto pelo HTML: `<a href="http://www.google.com.br" style="color: #4272DB">Google</a>`

Comment: Se não puder ser pela aba *code* como sugere o @Cigano, a pergunta é off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode ir diretamente no style do link:

```
<a href="#" style="color: #F00">teste</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Construa um [seletor CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/CSS/Como_come%C3%A7ar/Seletores) que atinja somente o link que você quer colorir, e crie a seguinte regra no seu CSS:

```css
seu-seletor {
    color: #f00; /* vermelho - troque para a cor que quiser */
}
```

O caminho mais curto é colocar um ID único no link, e criar um seletor de acordo. Por exemplo, um link assim:

```
<a href="#" id="meulink">Bla bla bla</a>
```

requer um seletor assim:

```css
#meulink { color: #f00; }
```

Comment: Agradeço a todos que responderam.
Depois de algum estudo consegui editar meu link.
Sou novo no Stackoverflow e a resposta mais próxima foi a última!

Estava com dificuldades em criar um estilo css e depois aplica-lo.

Depois de criado, não sabia como usar.